# Count size of islands with no gaps

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, gaps-and-islands

My data has 3 columns; ID, NAME, VALUE
ID is sequential number like a rowcount
There are many different NAMEs  I show 3 in the data but there could be 10+
There are 2 VALUEs

I would like to group the NAMEs and VALUEs in a 'local' manner and return the size of these 'local' groups.  This seems like a version of the Islands and Gaps scenario but no Gaps and Islands of repeating values.  I've tried variations on solutions to Islands and Gaps but so far, no real progress.

One of my failed attempts at a partial solution ( a variation on work by Itzik Ben-Gan):

```
WITH A
AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) RN,
           NAME,
           VALUE
    FROM #data
    WHERE NAME LIKE '%Joe%'),
T
AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RN) - RN AS Grp,
           RN
    FROM A
    WHERE VALUE = 0)
SELECT MIN(T.RN) AS [From],
       MAX(T.RN) AS [To],
       MAX(T.RN) - MIN(T.RN) AS [Length]
FROM T
GROUP BY Grp
ORDER BY MIN(T.RN);
```

Output like:

| NAME | VALUE | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 0 | 15 |
| Joe | 1 | 3 |
| Joe | 0 | 5 |
| Joe | 1 | 19 |
|  |  |  |
| Sue | 1 | 23 |
| Sue | 0 | 17 |
| Sue | 1 | 4 |
|  |  |  |
| Mary | 0 | 16 |
| Mary | 1 | 10 |
| Mary | 0 | 7 |
| Mary | 1 | 19 |
| Mary | 0 | 3 |

Where the data is like:

| ID | NAME | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 0 |
| 2 | Joe | 0 |
| 3 | Joe | 0 |
| 4 | Joe | 0 |
| 5 | Joe | 0 |
| 6 | Joe | 0 |
| 7 | Joe | 0 |
| 8 | Joe | 0 |
| 9 | Joe | 0 |
| 10 | Joe | 0 |
| 11 | Sue | 1 |
| 12 | Sue | 1 |
| 13 | Sue | 1 |
| 14 | Sue | 1 |
| 15 | Sue | 1 |
| 16 | Sue | 1 |
| 17 | Sue | 1 |
| 18 | Sue | 1 |
| 19 | Sue | 1 |
| 20 | Sue | 1 |
| 21 | Sue | 1 |
| 22 | Sue | 1 |
| 23 | Sue | 1 |
| 24 | Sue | 1 |
| 25 | Sue | 1 |
| 26 | Sue | 1 |
| 27 | Mary | 0 |
| 28 | Mary | 0 |
| 29 | Mary | 0 |
| 30 | Mary | 0 |
| 31 | Mary | 0 |
| 32 | Mary | 0 |
| 33 | Mary | 0 |
| 34 | Mary | 0 |
| 35 | Joe | 0 |
| 36 | Joe | 0 |
| 37 | Joe | 0 |
| 38 | Joe | 0 |
| 39 | Joe | 0 |
| 40 | Joe | 1 |
| 41 | Joe | 1 |
| 42 | Joe | 1 |
| 43 | Joe | 0 |
| 44 | Joe | 0 |
| 45 | Joe | 0 |
| 46 | Joe | 0 |
| 47 | Joe | 0 |
| 48 | Joe | 1 |
| 49 | Joe | 1 |
| 50 | Mary | 0 |
| 51 | Mary | 0 |
| 52 | Mary | 0 |
| 53 | Mary | 0 |
| 54 | Mary | 0 |
| 55 | Mary | 0 |
| 56 | Mary | 0 |
| 57 | Mary | 0 |
| 58 | Mary | 1 |
| 59 | Mary | 1 |
| 60 | Mary | 1 |
| 61 | Mary | 1 |
| 62 | Mary | 1 |
| 63 | Mary | 1 |
| 64 | Mary | 1 |
| 65 | Mary | 1 |
| 66 | Mary | 1 |
| 67 | Mary | 1 |
| 68 | Mary | 0 |
| 69 | Sue | 1 |
| 70 | Sue | 1 |
| 71 | Sue | 1 |
| 72 | Sue | 1 |
| 73 | Sue | 1 |
| 74 | Sue | 1 |
| 75 | Sue | 1 |
| 76 | Sue | 0 |
| 77 | Sue | 0 |
| 78 | Sue | 0 |
| 79 | Sue | 0 |
| 80 | Sue | 0 |
| 81 | Sue | 0 |
| 82 | Sue | 0 |
| 83 | Sue | 0 |
| 84 | Mary | 0 |
| 85 | Mary | 0 |
| 86 | Mary | 0 |
| 87 | Mary | 0 |
| 88 | Mary | 0 |
| 89 | Mary | 0 |
| 90 | Mary | 1 |
| 91 | Mary | 1 |
| 92 | Mary | 1 |
| 93 | Mary | 1 |
| 94 | Mary | 1 |
| 95 | Mary | 1 |
| 96 | Mary | 1 |
| 97 | Mary | 1 |
| 98 | Mary | 1 |
| 99 | Mary | 1 |
| 100 | Mary | 1 |
| 101 | Sue | 0 |
| 102 | Sue | 0 |
| 103 | Sue | 0 |
| 104 | Sue | 0 |
| 105 | Sue | 0 |
| 106 | Sue | 0 |
| 107 | Sue | 0 |
| 108 | Sue | 0 |
| 109 | Sue | 0 |
| 110 | Sue | 1 |
| 111 | Sue | 1 |
| 112 | Sue | 1 |
| 113 | Sue | 1 |
| 114 | Joe | 1 |
| 115 | Joe | 1 |
| 116 | Joe | 1 |
| 117 | Joe | 1 |
| 118 | Joe | 1 |
| 119 | Joe | 1 |
| 120 | Joe | 1 |
| 121 | Joe | 1 |
| 122 | Joe | 1 |
| 123 | Joe | 1 |
| 124 | Mary | 1 |
| 125 | Mary | 1 |
| 126 | Mary | 1 |
| 127 | Mary | 1 |
| 128 | Mary | 1 |
| 129 | Mary | 1 |
| 130 | Mary | 1 |
| 131 | Mary | 1 |
| 132 | Mary | 0 |
| 133 | Mary | 0 |
| 134 | Mary | 0 |
| 135 | Joe | 1 |
| 136 | Joe | 1 |
| 137 | Joe | 1 |
| 138 | Joe | 1 |
| 139 | Joe | 1 |
| 140 | Joe | 1 |
| 141 | Joe | 1 |

Comment: 1) I'll try to find one of them, or maybe try again and then post that. 2) This is just about as small of a sample as I can provide.  The actual data is over a million rows a day.  3) Not sure how that works but I'll try to find out.

Comment: Added one of my failed attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #data;
CREATE TABLE #data 
(
    ID INT,
    NAME VARCHAR(50),
    VALUE INT
);
INSERT INTO #data values
(1  ,'Joe', 0    ),
(2  ,'Joe', 0    ),
(3  ,'Joe', 0    ),
(4  ,'Joe', 0    ),
(5  ,'Joe', 0    ),
(6  ,'Joe', 0    ),
(7  ,'Joe', 0    ),
(8  ,'Joe', 0    ),
(9  ,'Joe', 0    ),
(10 ,'Joe', 0    ),
(11 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(12 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(13 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(14 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(15 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(16 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(17 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(18 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(19 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(20 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(21 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(22 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(23 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(24 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(25 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(26 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(27 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(28 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(29 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(30 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(31 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(32 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(33 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(34 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(35 ,'Joe', 0    ),
(36 ,'Joe', 0    ),
(37 ,'Joe', 0    ),
(38 ,'Joe', 0    ),
(39 ,'Joe', 0    ),
(40 ,'Joe', 1    ),
(41 ,'Joe', 1    ),
(42 ,'Joe', 1    ),
(43 ,'Joe', 0    ),
(44 ,'Joe', 0    ),
(45 ,'Joe', 0    ),
(46 ,'Joe', 0    ),
(47 ,'Joe', 0    ),
(48 ,'Joe', 1    ),
(49 ,'Joe', 1    ),
(50 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(51 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(52 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(53 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(54 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(55 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(56 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(57 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(58 ,'Mary',    1    ),
(59 ,'Mary',    1    ),
(60 ,'Mary',    1    ),
(61 ,'Mary',    1    ),
(62 ,'Mary',    1    ),
(63 ,'Mary',    1    ),
(64 ,'Mary',    1    ),
(65 ,'Mary',    1    ),
(66 ,'Mary',    1    ),
(67 ,'Mary',    1    ),
(68 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(69 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(70 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(71 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(72 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(73 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(74 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(75 ,'Sue', 1    ),
(76 ,'Sue', 0    ),
(77 ,'Sue', 0    ),
(78 ,'Sue', 0    ),
(79 ,'Sue', 0    ),
(80 ,'Sue', 0    ),
(81 ,'Sue', 0    ),
(82 ,'Sue', 0    ),
(83 ,'Sue', 0    ),
(84 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(85 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(86 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(87 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(88 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(89 ,'Mary',    0    ),
(90 ,'Mary',    1    ),
(91 ,'Mary',    1    ),
(92 ,'Mary',    1    ),
(93 ,'Mary',    1    ),
(94 ,'Mary',    1    ),
(95 ,'Mary',    1    ),
(96 ,'Mary',    1    ),
(97 ,'Mary',    1    ),
(98 ,'Mary',    1    ),
(99 ,'Mary',    1    ),
(100    ,'Mary',    1),
(101    ,'Sue', 0),
(102    ,'Sue', 0),
(103    ,'Sue', 0),
(104    ,'Sue', 0),
(105    ,'Sue', 0),
(106    ,'Sue', 0),
(107    ,'Sue', 0),
(108    ,'Sue', 0),
(109    ,'Sue', 0),
(110    ,'Sue', 1),
(111    ,'Sue', 1),
(112    ,'Sue', 1),
(113    ,'Sue', 1),
(114    ,'Joe', 1),
(115    ,'Joe', 1),
(116    ,'Joe', 1),
(117    ,'Joe', 1),
(118    ,'Joe', 1),
(119    ,'Joe', 1),
(120    ,'Joe', 1),
(121    ,'Joe', 1),
(122    ,'Joe', 1),
(123    ,'Joe', 1),
(124    ,'Mary',    1),
(125    ,'Mary',    1),
(126    ,'Mary',    1),
(127    ,'Mary',    1),
(128    ,'Mary',    1),
(129    ,'Mary',    1),
(130    ,'Mary',    1),
(131    ,'Mary',    1),
(132    ,'Mary',    0),
(133    ,'Mary',    0),
(134    ,'Mary',    0),
(135    ,'Joe', 1),
(136    ,'Joe', 1),
(137    ,'Joe', 1),
(138    ,'Joe', 1),
(139    ,'Joe', 1),
(140    ,'Joe', 1),
(141    ,'Joe', 1);

-- first find the changes
WITH breaks AS 
(
    SELECT ID, NAME, VALUE, 
        IIF(LAG(VALUE, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ID) != VALUE, 1, 0) AS NewGrp 
    FROM #data
), 
-- then count how many breaks we have passed 
grouped AS 
(
    SELECT ID, NAME, VALUE, SUM(NewGrp) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ID) grp
    FROM breaks
)
-- group by that count
SELECT NAME, VALUE, COUNT(*)
FROM grouped
GROUP BY NAME, VALUE, grp
ORDER BY NAME, MIN(ID)
```

Comment: Works perfectly!  And so elegant.  Now I need to work my way through it and try to understand how it works.  Just wonderful!!